# Getting an error in downloading PyAudio from my powershell and cmd

Tags: python

**Hello friends,**
I am getting an error when I am trying to download the PyAudio module in python. And, yes I copied the pip install PyAudio from the website of pyAudio please guys help me and the problem is shown like this:
pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\new folder\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Everin-k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-07nuopc5\pyaudio_00730340754743aa9b4975c8bd6e8427\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Everin-k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-07nuopc5\pyaudio_00730340754743aa9b4975c8bd6e8427\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Everin-k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qnzl4njq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\new folder\python37\Include\PyAudio'
cwd: C:\Users\Everin-k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-07nuopc5\pyaudio_00730340754743aa9b4975c8bd6e8427
Complete output (9 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\new folder\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Everin-k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-07nuopc5\pyaudio_00730340754743aa9b4975c8bd6e8427\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Everin-k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-07nuopc5\pyaudio_00730340754743aa9b4975c8bd6e8427\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Everin-k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qnzl4njq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\new folder\python37\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Python is correctly installed and added in path right ?